# Make parent not expand to child's content

Tags: html, css

Well, I've been trying to make a horizontal menu-bar for a few day now, and I made the CSS as small as I could.
But I have a problem, I don't want the `ul li` element to scale to the contents of the `ul ul`. Any ideas how could I do that?
From what I know, as `ul li` elemets have the `display:inline-block` they will always scale to the contents.
This is what I've got:
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DemonS/8fazuju8/)

```css
 body,
 html {
   padding: 0px;
   margin: 0px;
   height: 200%;
 }
 .nav {
   postion: fixed;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   margin: 0px;
   height: 50px;
   color: #F5F5F5 !important;
   font-size: 0px;
 }
 .nav ul {
   list-style-type: none;
   postion: relative;
   margin-left: -40px;
 }
 .nav ul li {
   display: inline-block;
   line-height: 50px;
   font-size: 15px;
 }
 .nav ul ul {
   visibility: hidden;
 }
 .nav ul ul li {
   display: block;
   font-size: 15px;
   top: -100%;
 }
 .nav ul li:hover>ul {
   visibility: visible;
 }
 .nav {
   background: #35404F;
   border-bottom: 4px solid #17A697;
   font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
 }
 .nav ul li {
   transition: background 250ms ease-in;
 }
 .nav ul li:hover {
   background: #17A697;
 }
 .nav ul ul li {
   transition: background 250ms ease-in;
   background: #35404F;
 }
 .nav ul ul li:hover {
   background: #17A697;
 }
 .nav a {
   margin: 0px 20px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a>Hi there</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a>Here is </a>
        </li>
        <li><a>Awesome</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="aright"><a>Hi there</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a>Here is the awesomeness</a>
        </li>
        <li><a>Awesome</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `position:absolute` for `.nav ul ul` because if you don't specify position for that `ul` as absolute it'll inherit from its parent's position which is relative and in this case the parent element has as width the width of the content, consequently your `li` takes the width of the his child `ul` which is larger, the `absolute position` makes the `ul` independent.

http://jsfiddle.net/fy6wggo1/1/

Comment: Works, but can You explain?

Comment: @CozzmyCosmin I updated the answer, if things still not clear for you let me know.